# If AND with 3 conditions apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Im trying to make somthing like this:

```
IF( A>B && A>C && A >= D){
than do this;
}
```

¿Can an IF have 3 conditions?

Answer (score 1):

There can be any number of conditions in an `if()` statement.

Apps Script is JavaScript and therefore case-sensitive, and keywords such as `if` are spelled in lower case. It is a good practice to use lower case with variable names as well, like this:

```
if (a > b && a > c && a >= d) {
  // ...do something
}
```

See [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).